# Analog timepicker inside scrollView not displaying time chooser

Tags: android, timepicker

So, in portrait mode is displayed correctly, no matter if timePicker is in  scrollView or not.

[image]

Landscape mode when is inside scroolView.

[image]

Landscape mode when there is no scroolView.

[image]

[Edit] Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.aapps.groupalarmclock.NewAlarmActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:alpha="@dimen/background_transparency"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rl_cancle"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/click_effect"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
            android:id="@+id/iv_cancel"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cancel_done_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/cancel_done_right_margin"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_cancel"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_cancel" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/separator_height"
        android:background="@color/colorLineSeparator"
        android:id="@+id/v_cancel_done">
    </View>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rl_done"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/click_effect"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
            android:id="@+id/iv_done"
            android:src="@drawable/done"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cancel_done_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/cancel_done_right_margin"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:id="@+id/tv_done"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_done"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_done" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lltp">


        <TimePicker tools:targetApi="23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:timePickerMode="clock"
            android:background="#80FFFFFF"/>

     </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property in ScrollView for whether scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport or not.... By default its set to false and when opened in landscape mode, it doesn't work.

So set

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

inside Scrollview and it should work.

For more info - 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Just noticed this....   change this in scroll-view     `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Hmm..its weird, because I tested it and it worked for me. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: I edited question. On which api verision you tested?

Comment: It seems it's problem on api version 21. I tested on 23 in emulator now and it's work fine :/

Comment: Problem was that i have old activity.xml in layout-land and when I made changes I forgot delete old file. So yeah, your answer was really helpful, now works also on api 21. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh haha, happens! Np :)

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue on device with Android 5.1 (API 22) but `android:fillViewport="true"` doesn't solve this in my case. But if we add additional layout as parent for TimePicker we can solve this.

The following example shows fixed layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TimePicker
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onSave"
                android:text="Save" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that TimePicker is placed inside LinearLayout which has `android:minHeight="200dp"` parameter and TimePicker itself has `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. This helps solve issue in ladscape orientation. `minHeight` parameter can has any value you need but should be used to render TimePicker properly.